# HTML plain characters from DB to DOCX

Tags: phpword

I am modifying an e-commerce website. The product description is stored in the database as follow:

```
&#60;p&#62;Product description&#60;/p&#62;
```

As you can see above, the HTML code is stored as plain characters. When I take this info from the DB and use it to create the docx document, the text in the Word document is shown as HTML code:

```
<p>Product description</p>
```

I already tried with different functions: html_entity_decode, htmlentities, htmlspecialchars. Maybe I am using them in the wrong order or just I am doing it in the wrong way.

Any ideas how to convert those characters to readable text in the Word document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. I used \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, html_entity_decode($html));

The html_entity_decode function made the job :D